# External JS file causing my webpage to appear blank

Tags: javascript

I'm making a browser-based clone of an old strategy game called Diplomacy. This is what I've got so far:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Diplomacy</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js" />

</head>


<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="750" style="border: 3px solid black; background:url('DiplomacyMap.png');">
Your browser does not support Canvas.
</canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

What does it look like in-browser? A blank page. However, if I remove the link to the external JS file in the head (game.js), it shows up no problem. This doesn't appear to have to do with the contents of the JS file, as even if I delete them or comment them all out, the problem persists. It seems to be to do with the mere presence of the  element.

If I replace the `<script src="file.js">` element with an embedded `<script> ...code... </script>`, the page works fine.

So... what's going on?

PART 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
colorProvince(PARIS, FRANCE);
</script>
```

Although the colorProvince function and the PARIS and FRANCE constants are all defined in game.js, this function isn't being called (as verified by a simple alert() in the colorProvince function). This doesn't do anything, either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(colorProvince);
</script>
```

Comment: The 2nd part really should be a separate question.  Also without seeing how `game.js` is defined it's going to be difficult to answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js" />
```

needs to be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
```

and in game.js there is an extra semicolon in `colorProvince()`. replace it with this:

```
function colorProvince(province, nation){
    alert(5);
    for (var i = 0; i < province.getRectangles().length; i++)
    {
        //colorRect(rect, "red");
    }
}
```

Comment: This, and you don't need the `type="text/javascript"` attribute

Comment: @tim, yes, quite often you do.  It's required for XHTML 1.0, for example.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen the browser won't care, though.

Comment: Thanks. I could have sworn I'd tried that. But here's a second problem I've added another script tag to the page body, and it's not able to use any functions defined in game.js. I'll add that to the end of the OP.

Comment: It's bad practice to not put it in there. I agree with Matthew.

Comment: @Jack, my best guess would be a scope issue but I could only know for sure if you showed us game.js why dont you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of it

Comment: I don't really know how to use jsFiddle so just to be on the safe side I've just pasteBin'd it: http://pastebin.com/JQEsjhNg

Comment: Updated my answer. Using the chrome debugger or firebug will really help you debug your game from now on.

Answer (score 1):

`<script>` tags can not be self closed. They **have** to have an ending tag, otherwise most browsers will choke.

Instead of `<script />` Use `<script></script>`